# Scaling a centered image with window size

Tags: css, scale, center, scaling

```
img.logo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -134px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    resize: both;
```

That's the code I'm using. It's a combination of resizing and centering, and yet it's only centering for some reason. I need the image to scale because, as it is currently, it's overlapping with an upper element of the page at very small browser sizes.

Comment: Depending on the context, you could consider setting image resolution based on media query breakpoints

Comment: How? I apologize for any ignorance, I'm not a coder by trade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using CSS media queries. Basically we define breakpoints based on screen width/browser width, and adjust the image widths accordingly.

```
img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    img { width: 500px; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    img { width: 400px; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    img { width: 300px; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
    img { width: 200px; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 200px) {
    img { width: 100px; }
}
```

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3SQE7/1/)

Hope this can suit your needs

**EDIT:**
You could even combine the above suggestion with `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` to keep the image centered at all times. For instance:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    ...
}
...
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3SQE7/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Scaling here works well, but the image is not centered (both horizontally and vertically).

Comment: You can add or adjust more options/properties, not just width as in the example above. For instance you could use the CSS from your question as a base, and then adjust both width and margins/positions using the @media queries to make sure the image remains centered

Comment: Updated the answer to include a way to make the image remain centered

Comment: That's about what I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple % for implementing the image width and height and the rest will take care automatically. The overlapping here I think is because the image is trying to maintain proportions with the auto attribute.

Or else you can try something like this in css

```
img.resize{
    width:60%; /* Use either % or px*/
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The overlapping occurs when there is no scaling, only centering. Ideally, the scaling would prevent any overlapping, because the centered image would be too small to make contact with the element above it. 

Still, I replaced what I had for width with a percent and the image moved to the left of the page and didn't scale.

Comment: Another way you can fix this is by using responsiveness for your images that is using media queries for different display platforms

Comment: I think your positioning is taking the toll on your image. Try changing them with different position: attributes. Check this for an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Tried them all, no such luck.